# Passing an array as a built-in function parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, call, apply

I need to pass an array as built-in function. For example this works fine:

```
console.info('%cBlue text%c Red text', 'color:blue', 'color:red');
```

There are 3 parameters, but what should I do when I got n parameter?

```
var x = [ '%cBlue text%c Red text...%c nth-Text', 'color:blue', 'color:red', ... , 'nth-color:black']; 
console.info.apply(null, x);
```

does not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you pass `null` as context instead of the `console` object. This works :

```
console.info.apply(console, x);
```

More generally, you can use `apply` for your own functions too, but when they need a context, you must set it.

Comment: Thank you dystroy, i got the idea.